# Issue with node while building svelte application in cloudflare pages

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit, cloudflare-pages

When I try and deploy my svelte project in Cloudflare pages I get this error

> 22:58:31.466  Cloning repository...
> 22:58:32.245    From https://github.com/ehubbartt/ethanhub
> 22:58:32.245     * branch            7807b7d14bc466249b9955d9ef06431003cd53ac -> FETCH_HEAD
> 22:58:32.246
> 22:58:32.295    HEAD is now at 7807b7d sdfs
> 22:58:32.295
> 22:58:32.438
> 22:58:32.464    Success: Finished cloning repository files
> 22:58:33.142    Installing dependencies
> 22:58:33.155    Python version set to 2.7
> 22:58:35.570    Attempting node version 'NODE_VERSION=12.18.0' from .nvmrc
> 22:58:37.196    Version 'NODE_VERSION=12.18.0' not found - try `nvm ls-remote` to browse available versions.
> 22:58:37.199    Failed to install node version 'NODE_VERSION=12.18.0'
> 22:58:37.204    Failed: build command exited with code: 1
> 22:58:38.110    Failed: an internal error occurred

Here is whay my .nvmrc file contains

```
NODE_VERSION=12.18.0
```

And I also have the environment variable set for the page.

```
NODE_VERSION=12.18.0
```

I have tried setting the version to many different things but can't quite get it to work and build

Comment: Since Sveltekit is still in beta, it's possible something broke during recent updates (bit me for another reason) You might try switching the adapter to `@sveltejs/adapter-cloudflare` and see if it works. Also note that Sveltekit requires Node 14.13 or later, so make sure you are asking for a compatible Node version.